# I want to Connect Sparkplug with AWS-Iot and publish/subscribe topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, mqtt-sparkplug

I am facing issue when connecting Sparkplug with AWS-IOT.
Can we use this "const AWSIoTData = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');" this import to connect sparkplug?

Iam able to receive data from "mqtt topic" .but same code if i keep sparkplug topic, i could not receive data even topic subscribed.

const client = AWSIoTData.device({
region: 'us-east-1',
host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
clientId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx',
protocol: 'wss',
maximumReconnectTimeMs: 5000,
debug: true,
accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
secretKey: secretAccessKey,
sessionToken: sessionToken
});

```
     client.on('connect', function () 
      {
        console.log('-------Connected---------'+thingName1);
       
        client. subscribe("spBv1.0/GROUP/#/NDATA", (error) => {
        if (error) {
        console. error('Subscription error:', error);
        }
        else {
        console.log('Subscribed to topic'); // I am able to subscribed sparkplug topic.
        }
    });


    client. on('message', function(payload, data) 
      {
        console.log('-Message received--', data); // It is going into this message block

      });
```

Please give me correct solution.

Thank you

I want to subscribe splark plug topic and will get data from sparkplug topic